# How do I install RabbitMQ-server on Jessie in Docker?

Tags: docker, debian, rabbitmq

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ docker run -it --rm debian:stable
root@d59276cca29d:/# apt-get update
...
root@d59276cca29d:/# apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server
...
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.3.5-1.1) ...
Adding group `rabbitmq' (GID 110) ...
Done.
Adding system user `rabbitmq' (UID 106) ...
Adding new user `rabbitmq' (UID 106) with group `rabbitmq' ...
Not creating home directory `/var/lib/rabbitmq'.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18) ...
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.3.5-1.1) ...
Adding group `rabbitmq' (GID 110) ...
Done.
Adding system user `rabbitmq' (UID 106) ...
Adding new user `rabbitmq' (UID 106) with group `rabbitmq' ...
Not creating home directory `/var/lib/rabbitmq'.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18) ...
root@d59276cca29d:/# service rabbitmq-server start
[warn] Starting message broker: rabbitmq-server[....] FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\} ... (warning).
 failed!
root@d59276cca29d:/# ls -l /var/log/rabbitmq/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 0 Aug  3 03:04 startup_err
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 0 Aug  3 03:04 startup_log
```

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine but maybe it mirrors profanity in the TL;DR section?

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug that's fixed in Stretch:

```
$ docker run -it --rm debian:testing
(run installation commands as in question above)
...
root@cd4e2b226156:/# service rabbitmq-server start
[ ok ] Starting message broker: rabbitmq-server.
```